# How to have multiple Lua files when working with Corona SDK?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am new to developing with the Corona SDK as well as Lua.
Currently i work strictly with the main.lua file.
Is there any way in Lua (im sure there is) to break up the source code into logical, separate files?

Example:
1. Main.lua
2. Entity.lua
3. Settings.lua

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a sample I wrote to demo what you're asking about: http://developer.anscamobile.com/code/object-oriented-sample-game-framework

EDIT: The forum post no longer seems to exist, so here's a link to download the sample code https://app.box.com/shared/uz5beg19h8

It divides things up into multiple files, and uses a sort of decorator pattern to add functionality like "level" or "floating character".

Answer (score 15):

**objects.lua**:

```
local M = {}
M.a = 3
return M
```

**main.lua**:

```
local objects = require('objects')
println(objects.a) --> 3
```

A very good discussion about this is available in the Lua users' wiki: http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaModuleFunctionCritiqued. You should read it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to only work with main.lua file. You can create separate **.lua** file as you need it like -

1- If you are using many scenes/views/classes for this you can create your separate **.lua** file for different scenes/views/classes and call these separate **.lua** files by using **storyboard**.

2- You can also create separate **.lua** files for creating **objects** which you can access in your any class.

3- There are many **.lua** files like **appirater.lua , ui.lua, json.lua** provided.